# How to get the access from one module's fields to second angular 13

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app and I want to get the access to the user's field inside the message module.

Message.ts interface:

```typescript
export interface Message {
  id: number;
  header: string;
  text: string;
  tag: string;
  authorUsername: string;
  likeCount: number;
  userId:number;
}
```

Message service method form find all messages page:

```typescript
getAll(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(this.apiURL + 'api/message/get',{},this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      )
}
```

My find all page component code:

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

  messages: Message[] = [];

  // @Input() header =''
  deleted = false;
  constructor(public messageService: MessageService,
              private toastr:ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.messageService.getAll().subscribe((data: Message[])=>{
      this.messages = data;
      console.log(this.messages);
    })

  }

  deletePost1(id:number){
    this.messageService.delete(id).subscribe(res => {
      this.toastr.success("Post Deleted");
      this.messages = this.messages.filter(item => item.id !== id);
      console.log('Post deleted successfully!');
    },
      ()=>{
      this.toastr.error("Can't delete! Something went wrong")
      })
  }

  infoPost(messageId: number){
    //showModalInfo(messageId);
    console.log("info post:" + messageId)
  }

}
```

Find all page html (I hardcoded first name and last name from user) and I want to catch them from user like : `'{{user.firstName}}'`

```html
<div>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="col-md-3 left-body">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 center-body">
      <div class="create_message_box_wrapper d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="d-flex user-info-box align-items-center">
          <div class="user-avatar">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300?random=1" id="user-logo">
          </div>
          <div class="user-info">
            <p>First name: Oleg</p>
            <p>Last name: Petrenko</p>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="create_message_box d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
          <a href="#" routerLink="create" class="btn btn-primary create_message_button ">Create New Message</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let message of messages">
          <app-messageblock [message]="message" (deleteEvent)="deletePost1($event)" (infoEvent)="infoPost($event)"></app-messageblock>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 right-body"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

User.ts interface:

```typescript
export interface User {
  id: number,
  username: string,
  email: string,
  role: string,
  status: string,
  password:string,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  cityId: number,
  regionId: number,
  countryName: string,
  genderName: string,
  userId: number,
  file:File,
}
```

User service method I want to use in my message find all page:

```typescript
find(id:number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get(this.apiURL + 'api/user/' + id, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.errorHandler)
      )
  }
```

My  files hierarchy (message):

[image]

user:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting the user id to pass to `find()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `find()` method is inside an angular service, to get a user inside any component you need to:

1. Inject the service into the constructor of the component.

```js
constructor(private userService: UserService) {}
```

2. Call the function inside oyur component, I'll assume that you already know the current user's id, so we can call it in ngOnInit. Store the data in a variable.

```js
user?: User;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.userService.find(id).subscribe((user) => this.user = user);
}
```

Now because the user will be undefined while we wait for a response, we will have to put a conditional statement in our html. Use `{{}}` to embed javascript / typescript into the html.

```html
<p>First name: {{user ? user.firstName : ""}}</p>
<p>Last name: {{user ? user.lastName : ""}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you a lot but I don't know what  id I should write in the signature of the find method (id is colored in red cause the app don't know what is it)

Comment: You will need to get the id of the user you want, I don't know how your app works so I can't tell you how to get it, sorry. Usually the function that logs a user in returns their id and stores it somewhere, or you'd have a function in the user service to retrieve it. Or better yet, there would be a function to get all of the current user's data.